# Filtered object not returning list in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, pagination

We are working with Angular Js application with spring in back-end. I need filtered list of items got from applying filters from table.

```
<tr class="ng-scope" dir-paginate="art in filteredItems=(vm.arts|filter:search | orderBy:sortKey:reverse) | itemsPerPage: 10" ng-include="getTemplate(art)"></tr>
```

But **filteredItems** is undefined/not getting values in controller. Same filteredItems was working when `ng-repeat` used instead of `dir-paginate`.

I need pagination on my table, so I have to use dir-paginate in tr.
How can I get filteredItems with dir-paginate.

This are complete html page :

```
<div style="min-height:650px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li style="margin-right: -1px;" class="active" ng-bind-html-unsafe="All">
            <a class="tabbar" data-toggle="tab"> Artifacts </a>
        </li>
        <a style="float: right;font-size: 20px;margin-right: 12px;margin-top: 5px;" ng-click="vm.exportArtifactsToCSV()" class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></a>
        </ul>   
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-11 col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 5%;margin-top: 1%;margin-bottom: 1%;">
                <span style="color: #669933;"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" ui-sref="art.new"
                                                 aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Artifacts" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="jh-table table table-striped" style="border: 1px solid grey;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;" ng-show="!(vm.roles.length == 1 && vm.roles.indexOf('ROLE_READONLY') > -1)"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;"></th>                     
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid grey;"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid white;"></th>
                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid white;"></th>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" ng-show="!(vm.roles.length == 1 && vm.roles.indexOf('ROLE_READONLY') > -1)"></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a ng-click="sort('artName')"
                                                                                                                                       style="cursor: pointer"
                                                                                                                                       class="ng-isolate-scope">Artifact Name<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='artName'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a
                            ng-click="sort('bucket.bucketShortName')"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            class="ng-isolate-scope">&nbsp;Bucket&nbsp;<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='bucket.bucketShortName'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>                      
                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a ng-click="sort('artMedium')"
                                                                                                                                       style="cursor: pointer"
                                                                                                                                       class="ng-isolate-scope">Medium<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='artMedium'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a
                            ng-click="sort('artSource')"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            class="ng-isolate-scope">Source<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='artSource'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a
                            ng-click="sort('application.id')"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            class="ng-isolate-scope">User Interface App ID<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='application.id'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>

                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a
                            ng-click="sort('artDocumentumCabinet')"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            class="ng-isolate-scope">Cabinet<span
                            class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='artDocumentumCabinet'"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;border-right: 1px solid grey;" class="ng-scope"><a
                            ng-click="sort('artDocumentumType')"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                            class="ng-isolate-scope">Document
                            Type<span
                                class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='artDocumentumType'"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></a>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;" ng-show="!(vm.roles.length == 1 && vm.roles.indexOf('ROLE_READONLY') > -1)"></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.artName" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.artName.length" ng-click="search.artName=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.bucket.bucketShortName" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.bucket.bucketShortName.length" ng-click="search.bucket.bucketShortName=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.artMedium" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.artMedium.length" ng-click="search.artMedium=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.artSource" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.artSource.length" ng-click="search.artSource=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.application.id" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.application.id.length" ng-click="search.application.id=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.artDocumentumCabinet" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.artDocumentumCabinet.length" ng-click="search.artDocumentumCabinet=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" delete-if-empty style="display:block;padding-right: 5%;" ng-model="search.artDocumentumType" placeholder="Search"/><a ng-if="search.artDocumentumType.length" ng-click="search.artDocumentumType=''"><span class="icon clearFilter"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-include="getTemplate(art)" dir-paginate="art in (filteredItems=(vm.arts|filter:search|orderBy:sortKey:reverse)|itemsPerPage: 10)">
                    </tr> </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"
                                         template-url="/templates/dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <pre ng-show="showTotalResults" class="ng-binding">Total Results:{{(vm.arts|filter:search).length}}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;" ng-show="!(vm.roles.length == 1 && vm.roles.indexOf('ROLE_READONLY') > -1)" class="text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editArtifact(art)">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.artName}}</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.bucket.bucketShortName}}</td>  
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.artMedium}}</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.artSource}}</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.application.id}}</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.artDocumentumCabinet}}</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">{{art.artDocumentumType}}</td>   
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;" ng-show="!(vm.roles.length == 1 && vm.roles.indexOf('ROLE_READONLY') > -1)">
        <span style="display: inline-flex;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveArtifact($index)">Save</button>&nbsp;
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" ng-model="vm.selected.artName" ng-style="vm.selected.artName === '' && {'border-color': 'red'}"/></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_bucket" name="bucket" ng-model="vm.selected.bucket"
                ng-options="buckets as buckets.bucketShortName for buckets in vm.buckets track by buckets.id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </td>   
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_artMedium" name="artMedium" ng-model="vm.selected.artMedium">
            <option value="E">E</option>
            <option value="HC/E">HC/E</option>
            <option value="HC">HC</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
            <option value="WIP">WIP</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">
        <select required class="form-control" id="field_artSource" ng-style="vm.selected.artSource === '' && {'border-color': 'red'}"
                name="artSource" ng-model="vm.selected.artSource">
            <option value="Documentum">Documentum</option>
            <option value="Filenet">Filenet</option>
            <option value="FileCabinet">File Cabinet</option>
            <option value="SharedDrive">Shared Drive</option>
            <option value="Sharepoint">Sharepoint</option>
            <option value="Mobius">Mobius</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selected.artSource" ng-style="vm.selected.artSource === '' && {'border-color': 'red'}"/>--></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;">
        <select class="form-control" id="field_application" name="application" ng-model="vm.selected.application"
                ng-options="application as application.id for application in vm.applications track by application.id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" ng-model="vm.selected.artDocumentumCabinet"/></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid grey;"><input type="text" ng-model="vm.selected.artDocumentumType"/></td>   
</script>
```

And getTemplate in js :

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(art) {
            if (art !== undefined && art.id === vm.selected.id)
                return 'edit';
            else return 'display';
        };
```

How can I get filtered item with pagination to work. I have tried by adding ng-include in span but not worked, data is not displayed. Also not worked with div.

How can I get filteredItems?

Comment: define the `filteredItems` variable in controller scope

Comment: @azad as I have mentioned this was working fine with ng-repeat then also filteredItems was not defined. Also I have defined then also not getting values of filter.

Comment: It looks like the problem with dir-paginate configuration. Try removing other filters (search, orderby) and see if it worked. Check the console for errors.

Comment: can you add  your full html code or mock code segment to question?

Comment: If I remove ng-include from tr then it work. But this is required as I have to perform in-line editing.

Comment: You can do someting like that `<tr class="ng-scope" dir-paginate="art in filteredItems=(vm.arts|filter:search | orderBy:sortKey:reverse) | itemsPerPage: 10"><span ng-include="getTemplate(art)"></span></tr>`

Comment: @GabrieleCiech I have tried this, but adding span not solving the problem. Actually getTemplate method return whether to display grids or edit the grids and according to selected criteria grids are displayed.

Comment: @azad Thanks for your help, but still problem not resolved. I have updated question with html and js code.